# C language printf add additional useless message

Tags: c, linux, printf, c-strings, conversion-specifier

I tried to simulate the linux file permission use st_mode, but when I print the result, it has an additional unwanted message.

```
/* file permission */
  char buf[9] = {0};
  char tmp_buf[] = "rwxrwxrwx";
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (sta.st_mode & (1 << (8 - i))) buf[i] = tmp_buf[i];
    else buf[i] = '-';
  }
  printf("%s", buf);
```

Here is my code, but the result is something like 'rw-rw-r--rwxrwxrwx'
and the strlen(buf) is 18.... Can someone help? I am not sure why temp_buf is appended to 'buf'

Comment: `char buf[10] = {0};`

Comment: You are writing 9 non-zero characters to `buf` and not terminating it.

Comment: Or `printf("%.*s", (int) sizeof buf, buf);`

Comment: The `"%s"` format specifier is only for strings, not arrays of chacters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion specifier `%s` expects an argument that represents a string. However it seems that the array `buf` does not contain a string.

Either enlarge the array with one more byte for the terminating zero

```
char buf[10] = {0};
```

or just use (specifying the precision before the conversion symbol `s`)

```
printf("%.9s", buf);
```

or alternatively

```
printf( "%.*s", ( int )sizeof( buf ), buf );
```